# Astable multivibrator using op amps - why does it start?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, multivibrator, astable

I'm new to electronics and I'm learning some circuits with op amps. Now I have been shown [this astable multivibrator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5YCsA2ATIq0AckDMYwBOAFkMOUmQHZ1CRkIxIRFnEBTAWgICgBDELkjFByLCGK5Uo8eKQhuGJvDgtoiYlURYsxRGFQUqyEVXXxCxsFUJZWhRisg8A7oOGDE0oSJ9QeAE7uvh6S3h7MynCuElLBsd5i-m5hMgnpzkGpqX6pkU4xfri68XmBpXGokOJ54AUA5iBVNZXVEiZQ-gDG8X7N8czEXFRqGlo6egZGHTBwYDyN-X1tuLjInc5rLYk15GnMzsR4LKjiq+vIKBKqkWAA+mDId5B3xKiGd1XP0PcvqA-3XA8La9LxNGieaQHYFJIolVAQ4oiaFAA).

[image]

I understand how it works.

1. The op amp is saturated at one side or the other
2. Voltage is divided and a portion of it goes to non-inverting input.
3. Voltage also charges the capacitor until it gets equal to the voltage on the non-inverting output
4. At that point the op amp swaps its output to the other saturation point.

**Why is the op amp saturated at point 1 to begin with?**

If I remove the capacitor (either shorting it, opening it or replacing it with a resistance), the op amp will sit at zero volts, since both inputs are zero, and that is totally what I would expect.

[image]

Why, by plugging in an **uncharged capacitor**, does the op amp suddenly decides to saturate?

The *uncharged* capacitor should not create any change in the difference of voltage between inverting and non inverting inputs that the op amp could amplify, so I would expect that in a perfect simulation this circuit would not start oscillating in the first place unless the capacitor does hold a tiny bit of charge.

Why does it start oscillating?

**EDIT:** so it turns out that in the simulator the capacitor actually *had* an initial voltage, and indeed if I set it to zero then the simulation will not oscillate.

Comment: It is starting due to thermal noise.Many oscillators start from thermal noise.

Comment: so it starts from a non-ideal situation that is coded inside the simulator that otherwise deals with ideal components? sound like a very specific coding problem to find cases where thermal noise should change the simulation vs the rest of situations.
Or am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: Thermal noise starts the oscillations and it gets amplified until it is not.It is not about ideality of components.

Comment: Thanks, IRL the cap would "integrate" a bit of that noise to create a diferencie in the inputs and start the oscilator? otherwise the same noise would be equal at both inputs so the change in them would still be zero, right?
Sorry if this are stupid questions, I have never really dealt with noise as a usefull part of a circuit before.

Comment: Yes but you will have noise to the output as well and because this is a closed loop configuration(with feedback) and the voltage dividers and the circuit is asymmetric (bottom you have a voltage divider , top dont have) you will get a voltage between the inverting and the non-inverting terminal.

Comment: No, the default falstad cap has a small  charge by default as a parameter when created which has to be edited to zero for it to actually have zero initial charge.

Comment: I am not talking about falstad , i am talking about the real circuit if you build it on a breadboard why the oscillation starts.

Comment: Sorry I was answering to another user that deleted his comment.
yes I understand what you say miss mulan, thanks!! that helps out a lot.

Comment: That means that a real OpAmp with an OPEN instead of that cap will saturate in the breadboard, right? (nos oscilate, just saturate to one rail)

Comment: Yes it will saturate.

Comment: That edit just saved me a lot of banging my head against a wall, thanks!!!.
It's making sense now.

Comment: Yeah sorry 9 min ago my mind was busy solving an exercise.

Comment: I had also scratched my head on this scenario during course work. Ideality can never explain this unlike in most of the ckts. In the real ckt, there will always be a tiny mismatch that triggers the oscillation.

Comment: The key element of an astable circuit, is that it  has a NON-STABLE equilibrium, which cannot persist, and a second solution which is  oscillatory.   So, regardless of how the initial conditions are arranged, you expect the oscillatory solution in the long-time evolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The uncharged cap should not create any change in the difference of voltage between inverting and non inverting inputs that the op-amp could amplify, so I would expect that in a perfect simulation this circuit would not start oscillating in the first place unless the capacitor does hold a tiny bit of charge.

You are correct and there are many questions on this site from people wondering why their simulation doesn't oscillate.

I suspect that your simulator (Falstad?) is introducing a little offset error or noise to more realistically simulate a real device specifically for applications such as yours. I think that a smart solution (for them) would be to introduce it in the power-up of the op-amp so that the output is pulled a little more than the other and once fully powered the component continues
with ideal performance.

Comment: You where right!, after checking it's properties it turns out the cap was not actually discharged on initial conditions in the simulator, probably for this reason. After setting it to zero initial charge and restarting the simulator, the  oscilator does not start.
However IRL, does the  capacitor hold a little bit of charge caused by external noise so that it creates a tiny difference in the inputs and starts the oscilation?

Comment: No, generally the capacitor would be discharged but the op-amp would be non ideal and will have some offsets on the inputs and won't power up symmetrically.

Comment: So it would actually output a small voltage that would charge a tiny bit the  capaciitor and start the whole thing.

Comment: Maybe. A real op-amp will have tiny input bias currents which might charge the capacitor a bit but notice that the feedback resistor would discharge it. A more likely scenario is that there is a slight offset voltage between the two inputs - say in the order of nV or uV - and when this is multiplied by the open-loop gain it will result in the output voltage deviating from zero enough to get things going.

Comment: ahhh so the OpAmp non-ideality means that both inputs are not at the same potential by minute differences.
I did simulate a small noise signal on one of the inputs with the cap discharged and it indeed starts oscilating after about a second or two.
https://tinyurl.com/yewm99ly
Thanks!

Comment: "Maybe. A real op-amp will have tiny input bias currents which might charge the capacitor a bit but notice that the feedback resistor would discharge it. A more likely scenario is that there is a slight offset voltage between the two inputs - say in the order of nV or uV - and when this is multiplied by the open-loop gain it will result in the output voltage deviating from zero enough to get things going.". But @Transistor this is a closed loop configuration.

Comment: @Miss, the circuit has a positive feedback loop which gives a Schmitt trigger action.

Comment: FYI, the simulator is called CircuitJS

Answer (score 6):

If you give the op-amp even a tiny bit of offset voltage when you connect the uncharged capacitor the output will slam to one rail or the other and oscillation begins.

Similarly, even if perfectly balanced on knife-edge, a microvolt of change in offset voltage will be amplified by perhaps 1,000,000 and the output again saturates, since that 1V becomes 500mV at the non-inverting input.

It’s possible for simulations that use too-ideal components to fail to start oscillating. Giving them a minute ‘kick’ or preventing them from seeking a perfect balance in the first place may help.

Comment: Notes about using (real) op amps [for comparator-like applications](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-849.pdf) could be included (*"However, the best advice on using an op amp as a comparator is very simple - don't!"*).